# Bash: redirect `cat` to file without newline

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, newline, cat

I have two files that I am concatenating into a single file, but I am also adding user input between the two files. The problem is that a newline is being inserted after the first file, the rest of it works as desired.

```
touch newFile
cat file1 > newFile
echo -n $userInput >> newFile
cat file2 >> newFile
```

How do I prevent or remove the newline when file1 is added to newFile? If I `cat file1` there seems to be a newline added by `cat` but everything I see about `cat` says it doesn't do that. If I `vim file1` there's not a blank line at the end of the file that would indicate the newline is a part of the file, so either `cat` is actually adding a newline, or the redirect `>` is doing it, or `echo` adds a newline at the beginning of its output, none of which would be desirable in this situation. One solution I saw was to use

```
cat file1 | tr -d '\n'
```

but that discards all the newlines in the file, also not desirable. So, to repeat my question:

How do I `cat file1` into the new file and add user input without adding the newline between them?

(`cat` is not a requirement, but I am not familiar with `printf`, so if that's the solution then please elaborate on its use).

Comment: `printf '%s' "$userInput"` is more reliable than `echo -n "$userInput"`; if you see [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), you'll notice that `-n` makes behavior implementation-defined, and that the `APPLICATION USAGE` section of the standard suggests `printf` in place of of either `echo -n` or any `echo` invocations with backslash-escape sequences.

Comment: Not sure why this question got voted down, clearly I was misunderstanding something that would not have been made clear by doing a reasonable amount of additional research, and I did enough research on my issue to recognize that the answers currently out there were insufficient to answer my specific question. I learned a number of new things by asking this question, thus it served its purpose. @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help and thorough explanations! I'm not a complete BASH/UNIX noob but there's plenty left for me to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With these inputs:

```
userInput="Test Test Test"

echo "Line 1
Line 2
Line 3" >file1

echo "Line 4
Line 5
Line 6" >file2
```

I would do:

```
printf "%s%s%s" "$(cat file1)" "$userInput" "$(cat file2)" >newfile
```

The creation of `>newfile` is equivalent to `touch` and adding content in your first step. A bit easier to see intent with this.

I get:

```
$ cat newfile
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3Test Test TestLine 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

Comment: I assume you want a 3rd `%s`, not a `$s` in the format string? Though `printf '%s' "$(cat file1)" "$userInput" "$(cat file2)"` would have the same effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, thanks but oddly enough it works anyway!

Comment: When the variable is empty, it would work the same way `%s%s` or `%s` does -- repeating the format string when it runs out of placeholders. When `s` is not empty, then things would be interesting. :)

Comment: Awesome, that's definitely a cleaner solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Like all other Unix tools, Vim considers `\n` a line *terminator* and not a line *separator*.

This means that a linefeed after the last piece of text will be considered part of the last line, and will not show an additional blank line.

If there is no trailing linefeed, Vim will instead show `[noeol]` in the status bar when the file is loaded:

```
foo
~
~
~
~
~
"file" [noeol] 1L, 3C            1,1           All
        ^---- Here
```

So no, the linefeed is definitely part of your file and not being added by bash in any way.

If you want to strip all trailing linefeeds, you can do this as a side effect of command expansion:

```
printf '%s' "$(<file1)" >> newfile
```

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks! I didn't realize VIM was "hiding" the newlines like that, so my question was based on a misunderstanding of where that newline was coming from.

Comment: I am between this answer and the one I selected, but the other one has the more elegant solution, but without this answer I would still be confused about the whole VIM thing. SO should add a feature to select multiple answers combined as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
touch newFile
echo -n "$(cat file1)" > newFile
echo -n $userInput >> newFile
cat file2 >> newFile
```

That did the trick.

Comment: Triple backticks are a GitHub addition to Markdown -- they aren't part of the baseline syntax, and not honored by the StackOverflow parser. Use four-space indents, as created by the `{}` button, for multi-line code formatting; this also enables syntax highlighting, which backtick-surrounded content doesn't get.

Comment: ...speaking to content rather than form, though -- you're actually **deleting** a line that existed in the file here; this is because `$(...)` removes the last newline from the output of `...` -- so your output has fewer newlines than the input files do; you're not passing content through without *adding* a newline, but rather **actively deleting** a newline when you do this.

Comment: (Also, you certainly want `"$userInput"`, not `$userInput`, unless you want a `*` to be replaced with a list of filenames in the directory where your code is run; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks again for all these explanations, I've been on Slack so much that I was using the triple backticks from force of habit. ... It also makes more sense now why "$(...)" actually worked the way it did. Between VIM "hiding" the newline and $(...) removing that newline, I was thoroughly confused at the behavior I witnessed. Thanks for explaining how that works! (Now, time to really learn printf, obviously it's something I should know by now)